# How to use Coroutines while using signInWithEmailAndPassword in Firebase Authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

I want to use coroutines in firebase for sign in function

```
 private suspend fun signin() {

    var email = binding.emailArea.text.toString()
    var password = binding.passwordArea.text.toString()
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).await()
    }
}
```

but I don't know what signing function really return.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val result = async { signin() }
    //how to utilize result?
}
```

I know that await returns deferred. But I don't know how to utilize this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`await`](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#kotlin_coroutine) method on `Task` is `suspend` and returns an `AuthResult` object for [`signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#public-taskauthresult-signinwithemailandpassword-string-email,-string-password) function:

```
private suspend fun signIn(): AuthResult? {
    try {
            // ... init email and password


            val authResult: AuthResult = signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).await()
            return authResult
            
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return null
        }
}

someCoroutineScope.launch { // launching a coroutine
    val authResult: AuthResult? = signIn()
    if (authResult == null) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        // use authResult for example to get FirebaseUser using authResult.getUser()
    }  
}
```

To launch a coroutine in Android instead of `someCoroutineScope` we can use `viewModelScope` in a `ViewModel` class, or `lifecycleScope` in `Activity`/`Fragment`.